# bt assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have quesetion about `bt` assembly instruction. I have excerpted part of book to provide context. Please see last example, `bt Testme, bx`. Why does that copy `TestMe+8`? Shouldn't it copy `TestMe+65`?

Very much thank you for help!

> #### 6.6.4.2 The Bit Test Instructions: BT, BTS, BTR, and BTC
>
> On an 80386 or later processor, you can use the bt instruction (bit
>   test) to test a single bit. Its second operand specifies the bit index
>   into the first operand. Bt copies the addressed bit into the carry
>   flag. For example, the instruction
>
> ```
>   bt  ax, 12
> ```
>
> copies bit twelve of ax into the carry flag.
>
> The bt/bts/btr/btc instructions only deal with 16 or 32 bit operands.
>   This is not a limitation of the instruction. After all, if you want to
>   test bit three of the al register, you can just as easily test bit
>   three of the ax register. On the other hand, if the index is larger
>   than the size of a register operand, the result is undefined.
>
> If the first operand is a memory location, the bt instruction tests
>   the bit at the given offset in memory, regardless the value of the
>   index. For example, if bx contains 65 then
>
> ```
>   bt  TestMe, bx
> ```
>
> will copy bit one of location TestMe+8 into the carry
>   flag. Once again, the size of the operand does not matter. For all
>   intents and purposes, the memory operand is a byte and you can test
>   any bit after that byte with an appropriate index. The actual bit bt
>   tests is at bit position index mod 8 and at memory offset effective
>   address + index/8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When the book says "bit one of location `TestMe+8`", the "`8`" refers to an *address offset*, which is measured in bytes.  There are 64 bits in 8 bytes, so the 65th bit is bit one of 8 bytes past `TestMe`.

- The byte at `TestMe` has bits 7..0
- The byte at `TestMe+1` has bits 15..8
- The byte at `TestMe+2` has bits 23..16
- ...
- The byte at `TestMe+8` has bits 71..64

So "65" refers to "bit 1" (the second counting from the right) of the byte at address `TestMe+8`.

Answer (score 3):

`bt TestMe, bx` where bx contains `65` is an access 8 bytes (64 bits plus 1) beyond the address of `TestMe`.  It doesn't copy the byte there, only the second bit in that byte (to the carry flag, CF).